# Maven build and dockerize Java Spring project

Tags: java, spring, maven, docker, jar

I'd like to automate process of maven build and build and run of docker containers(docker-compose if possible) with resulting jar file.
How do I do that with probably one maven command?

Answer (score 0):

Use [docker-maven-plugin](https://github.com/spotify/docker-maven-plugin)

You pom.xml will have the plugin like this

```
        <plugin>
            <groupId>com.spotify</groupId>
            <artifactId>docker-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>0.2.3</version>
            <configuration>
                <imageName>my-docker/${project.artifactId}</imageName>
                <dockerDirectory>./</dockerDirectory>
                <resources>
                    <resource>
                        <targetPath>/</targetPath>
                        <directory>${project.build.directory}</directory>
                        <include>${project.build.finalName}.jar</include>
                    </resource>
                </resources>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
```